# how to make aside bar in a column

Tags: html, css, angular

what i want to do is at the left of screen i mke a column with specific width ad height in which there is the user picture and just on the right of picture user name and position under this block i will add some titles .
the problem is when i put the block of titles they going out side the column ! how can i solve it and make it responsive by using bootstrab !
this the html :

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="left-part">
      <img src="assets/user.jpeg" alt="User Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="right-part">
      <div class="user-name">user</div>
      <div class="user-status">Operator</div>
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
        <div class="title">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          Title1
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          Title2
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          Title3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the SCSS :

```
.block{
    margin-top: 0%;
    display: flex;
    //align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 219px;
    height: 599px;
    left: 0px;



  
  .left-part {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 14px;
    margin-left: 14px;
  }
  
  .left-part img {
    width: 69 px;
    height: 80px;
   // border-radius: 50%;
   // object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .right-part {
    margin-top: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  
  .user-name {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .user-status {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    i {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is how i call my component in the page home :

```
<div>
    <app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular material, you can make use of the material component called side-nav.

Link you can refer to: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples